# html-css change img hover

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to change the image hover to another picture. What i have found has not worked for me yet. 
Here is my HTML

```
<div id="navbar">
    <table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="index.html"><div id="navbar_button" style="background-image: url(images/navbar_home.png); width: 213px;"></div></a></td>
            <td><a href="play.html"><div id="navbar_button" style="background-image: url(images/navbar_playnow.png); width: 213px;"></div></a></td>
            <td><a href="home/index.php"><div id="navbar_button" style="background-image: url(images/navbar_forum.png); width: 213px;"></div></a></td>
            <td><a href="highscores.php"><div id="navbar_button" style="background-image: url(images/navbar_highscores.png); width: 213px;"></div></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and my CSS

```
#navbar {
    background-image: url(../images/navbar_bg.png);
    height: 88px;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#navbar_button {
    height: 88px;
}
#navbar_button:hover {
    opacity:0.9;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90);
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you can't change the html? Otherwise it would be a good idea to move those inline `style="background-image: url(images/navbar_home.png); width: 213px;"` attributes into the css. You could give each `<div>` a unique class attribute.

Comment: what browser are you testing it on? "filter" in your css doesn't work on all browsers

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the same ID for more than one element. ID is unique identifier and should be unique, this is your problem.

So you need to change it to class instead of ID:

```
.navbar_button {
    height: 88px; 
    width: 213px;
} 
.navbar_button:hover { 
    opacity:0.9; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=90); 
}

<div id="navbar"> 
    <table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"> 
        <tr> 
            <td><a href="index.html"><div class="navbar_button" style="background-image: url(images/navbar_home.png);"></div></a></td> 
            <td><a href="play.html"><div class="navbar_button" style="background-image: url(images/navbar_playnow.png);"></div></a></td> 
            <td><a href="home/index.php"><div class="navbar_button" style="background-image: url(images/navbar_forum.png);"></div></a></td> 
            <td><a href="highscores.php"><div class="navbar_button" style="background-image: url(images/navbar_highscores.png);"></div></a></td> 
        </tr> 
    </table> 
</div>
```

But with this you can't change the image on hover, for image change you need to use ID and give every div another image + ID:

```
.navbar_button {
    height: 88px; 
} 
#navbar_button1:hover { 
    background-image: url(whatever1.png);
}
#navbar_button2:hover { 
    background-image: url(whatever2.png);
}

<div id="navbar"> 
    <table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"> 
        <tr> 
            <td><a href="index.html"><div class="navbar_button" id="navbar_button1" style="background-image: url(images/navbar_home.png); width: 213px;"></div></a></td> 
            <td><a href="play.html"><div class="navbar_button" id="navbar_button2" style="background-image: url(images/navbar_playnow.png); width: 213px;"></div></a></td> 
        </tr> 
    </table> 
</div>
```

**Another trick:** Use solution one with the classes and use one image that have the normal and hover state (tiled) on it (Left the normal state and right the hover image). Than just write in your css:

```
.navbar_button {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    height: 88px; 
    width: 213px;
} 
.navbar_button:hover {
    background-position:left;
    opacity:0.9; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=90); 
}
```

1. Your image on the image must match the height and width of the container, else it don't look good.
2. You have a bigger load on images, cause they are bigger in filesize
3. But you don't need to load the image on hover and there's no flicker on slower servers/browsers/bandwidth
4. with this you don't need to write ID for every image inside your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It's worked. Can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d77fx/).

Please check url of image, and was you intentionally set to 0.9 alpha?

Comment: It works, but the code is semantically wrong, you need to remove those multiple id's

Comment: @Jeemusu Right. 'id' attributes are should change to 'class'.

Answer (score 0):

modify your code like this

```
<td><div class="navbar_button" style="background-image: url(images/navbar_home.png); width: 213px;"><a href="index.html"></a></div></td>
```

and in css:
modify like this,

```
div.navbar_button a:hover {
opacity:0.9;
filter:alpha(opacity=90);
}
```

Id is unique one ..you cant repeat it.. so i used class instead of id.. try this..hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

ID is an unique identifier. You should have to use different id's 
Change your id's and try this:

```
.image-hover {
   display:block; /* if u need */
   background-image:url(http://first_image_url.jpg);
   width:100px; /* as your wish */
   height:100px; /* as your wish */
}
.image-hover:hover {
   background-image:url(http://second_image_url.jpg);
}
```

or use javascript `mouseover` and `mouseout`